# searching for reverse string in an file

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to make a script that looks inside a file that contains all words of my language (1 word per line), read it and checks if every single word in that file is in reverse in the file, basicly palindromes and semi-palindromes

```py
words = open('AllWords.txt', 'r')

for line in words:
    reverse = line[::-1]
    if reverse in words:
        print(reverse)
    if reverse not in words:
        continue
```

However it seems that after the first word in the file (which is not reverse in words) it stops iterating.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: You haven't said what your question is. What is the issue here? Do you get errors?

Comment: Palindromes are the same forward and backward. So count the number of appearances of each word. If every word appears twice or more, you have only palindromes, if not, you don't.

Comment: I do not get an error, but my program just stops it seems that after iterating over the first word it sees that it is not in in the 'words' file, when in reverse and than just stops the for loop, which is the end of my script

Comment: `words` is a file, when you say `if reverse in words`, you read the entire file, moving the file pointer to the end.

Comment: What is in your word object? Are you sure it is a list of words?

Comment: Hi BMW, I am not looking only for pallingdromes but also for words that mean something different in for example the name Lana and an*l (couldn't think of a beter example)

Comment: If you want to do it more efficiently, you can add each reversed word to a `set` and check the original word to see if it's in that set. You go from O(N^2) to O(N) but use an additional O(N) space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `word` is an iterator and the check `reverse in words` exhausts it. So for the next iteration of the `for` loop there is no further element available (the iterator is exhausted) and so it stops iterating.

You could use a `list` or `set` instead:

```
words = set(map(str.rstrip, open(...).readlines()))
```

Then perform the rest of the code as you've already indicated.

If order matters then you can use a `list` for the iteration and a `set` for the check (membership tests for sets are O(1)):

```
with open(...) as fh:
    words = [x.rstrip() for x in fh]
word_set = set(words)
for word in words:
    if word[::-1] in word_set:
        print(word)
```

You can also use two sets since the palindromes are the intersection between two sets, one for words and one for reversed words:

```
with open(...) as fh:
    words = set(map(str.rstrip, fh))
words_reversed = set(x[::-1] for x in words)
palindromes = words & words_reversed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = open('AllWords.txt', 'r').readlines()

for line in words:
    reverse = line[::-1]
    if reverse in words:
        print(reverse)
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but would be a lot better with an explanation of what you fixed.

Comment: `readlines` retains the `'\n'` newline character and it needs to be stripped to work with reversing the words.

Answer (score 0):

The process is going to be quite slow if you have a large number of words in your file.  You could get results much faster using set operations:

```
words = open("Allwords.txt").read().split("\n")
palindromes = set(words).intersection(w[::-1] for w in words)
for palindrome in palindromes: print(palindrome)
```